# Question disowned by author/moderator

Tags: discussion, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki)

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9933430/142162) a minute after it was posted, whose author was our friendly neighborhood moderator [NullUserException ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) (You can see on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933492/142162) that he posted a comment).

Returning to the question just a few minutes ago, I see the question's author is now anon:

[image: user]

I was just curious to why this happened, as the behavior seems a little odd.

Comment: Usually the only time I've seen this is when the devs enter the database and remove the user information directly. ~~ for the record, I can't disassociate myself from my questions on dba.se, and I'm a mod, so I don't think this can be abuse of privilege.

Comment: Yeah, let's not jump to conclusions in making accusations. I'm pretty sure this isn't a moderator power. At least I haven't found it...

Comment: @minitechη - mods can't anonymise posts, only devs can.

Comment: Okay, okay, never mind.

Comment: @minitechη What, you think if they could they'd tell you? Never trust a mod, youngling.

Comment: @YannisRizos: But then I can't trust your judgement.

Comment: @minitechη (shhh, I'm a spy behind enemy lines)

Comment: Moderators don't have the power to do dissociate/anonymize, only devs can. In general, we aren't supposed to do stuff to our own posts that a regular user can't anyways. But yes, I did what I would do if I were a regular user who doesn't want a question associated with them: I asked the team to handle it.

Comment: Looks like this could be tagged with [`[streisand-effect]`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Anyone can, upon request, have a post of theirs disassociated from their account. At that point, they lose ownership rights on the site: it won't appear in their account, they can't accept an answer (if it's a question), delete it (if it's an answer or unanswered question), or edit it (if they have less than the 2K reputation points needed to edit anything). And of course, votes on the post won't count toward their reputation on the site.

This isn't usually a big deal, but it does require administrator (not moderator) intervention, both to discourage its use and to allow us to more easily keep an eye out for potential abuse.

#### See also: [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki)