# Is there a way I can have my valid question deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, deleted-questions, moderators

I had asked a question, though it is a valid question and even may be useful for other web surfers. But I somehow feel that this is a silly question and I shouldn't have asked it, rather done a little Googling and I would have found the answer. I wanted to create a profile on Stack Overflow Careers but this question is preventing me, because this question in my opinion was very simple and I don't think I should have asked it at that time.

I am concerned that if I create a profile on stackoverflow careers, the question that I have asked may give a wrong interpretation about my abilities and skills to my future employers.

If I approach a moderator will he be able to delete it or what should I do?

Comment: You can ask for it to be disassociated from your account. Otherwise, I think the best option is to just ask enough good questions to bump it off your top 5 list.

Comment: @Mysticial: how does disassociation work.

Comment: It detaches the post from your account. The post itself will become owned by "anon". Only devs have this power, so you have to contact them. But since this is on meta, they'll probably see it anyway.

Comment: You don't even have to show the particular question on your Careers profile. You can remove it from showing up if you wish. (Though it would still be visible in your SO profile if someone would look)

Comment: Just a warning, if you do dissociate the post from your account, you lose all the drawbacks __and benefits__ of question ownership. Most importantly, you will no longer receive notifications of new activity at that question. You'll lose rep and badges you got for it, too.

Comment: If you found the answer, just post that as an answer.

Comment: Oh, one more thing, if you're really worried about this, you may want to eventually dissociate your account from _this_ question.

Comment: Just realized there's an FAQ entry about dissociation: [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki)

Comment: @PopularDemand: Thanks Buddy. that worked. I flagged and got rid of this

Comment: @refhat What if your future employers look at *this* question coming to Meta profile from your SO profile and found that you had one of your questions deleted? =P

Comment: @KingsIndian: smart...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Valid questions should not be deleted because they could be helpful to others.

But in your case, you seem to just want to hide it. So you can ask a dev to disassociate the post from your account. This will remove it from your account and replace the post's owner with "anon". However, you will also lose all rep you gained from it since it is no longer yours.

I think a better idea is to just ask enough good questions to bump it off your top-5 list. I used to have 5 silly answers on my top 5 list. But by changing my answering habits, I managed to push all but one of them off that top 5 list over the course of a few months.

Comment: Just for clarification "ask a dev to disassociate the post" actually means to flag it for moderation, right? Or is this done in some other way?

Comment: Yes, you can flag it. [But normal moderators don't actually have the power to disassociate posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127466/question-disowned-by-author-moderator#comment346558_127466). So they have to forward the request to a dev.

Comment: @Mysticial: I know how to contact a moderator but not sure how to get in touch with dev. who are dev's. Are they admin ppl.

Comment: I'd say just flag it. They'll forward it to the right people.

Comment: @Mysticial: I had already flaged it before. But my flag was rejected. May this time I can give them a link to this question on meta.

Comment: You probably asked for it to be deleted. That won't happen for valid questions - which is why it would get declined. But if you flag for disassociation, it should work. [It is within your legal rights to remove your name from any post.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki)

Comment: @refhat: Uh, please don't flag it.  Try emailing team@stackoverflow first.  Give it some time, this is low priority, you understand.

Comment: @Won't Your advice overrides mine. Should I clear out my comments telling him to flag?

Comment: @Won't: So I can have anything disassociated from my account if I wish. Any no. of questions/answers Right?,

Comment: @refhat: Dunno.  Its above my pay grade.  Oh, wait, I don't have a pay grade.  Its up to the people who do get paid to do stuff at SE to decide what they will do.  That's why you have to email them.