# Can an account be manually unassociated from my network profile?

Tags: support, openid, linked-accounts

I looked at similar questions and wanted to post a more specific one.

If I wanted one of my accounts on the network to no longer be associated to my global account, could an administrator do it manually? I mean, even if they could, would they?

It's a matter of professionalism. I don't want one of my accounts on the network to be visible from my other accounts. I just want that to be under a separate email that's not one of the OpenIDs associated with my global account.

I realize this would have been easier to do when I joined that site, but it's too late now, and only now have I realized that I don't really want that account showing up.

So can it be done by an administrator? I don't want to wait weeks and weeks for a response by using the contact form (funny, I've waited two with this post)...

Comment: As an alternative, you could always just ask to be [dissociated from specific posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki) that are problematic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I don't want to wait weeks and weeks for a response by using the contact form

You wouldn't have had to wait that long. But I'm happy to answer here instead - it's a common request.

And the answer is **no.**

You can *create* an account like this - just log out of everything, and sign up for a new one using completely different credentials. And then never, ever, let the two accounts touch in any way.

But once you have multiple profiles associated together under a single network-wide account, they stay that way.

In *some* circumstances we may be able to help you out, if you use the "contact us" link and let us know which site's profile you're looking to disassociate, and why you're looking to do so. But fair warning: it'll probably involve deleting that profile and simply associating the posts (not votes, not badges, not preferences or activity history...) with another one you've created.

So for now, save yourself the trouble and plan ahead.