# Can a user split their Stack Exchange network account into two independent ones?

Tags: support, user-accounts, linked-accounts, merge-accounts

This is basically a reverse of https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts.

Let's say a user has a single account on several SE sites that are linked (for example, Stack Overflow, Programmers, Gaming and RPG).

They want to expose their SO and Programmers professional accounts to a professional audience, but don't want anyone to link that to their more "frivolous" Gaming/RPG accounts.

Is it possible - as a one-time event - split that one SE account into two separate accounts? The assumption is that they would be 100% independent of each other, **with different logins**, and no further association between them? If so, what would be the procedure?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197600/allow-users-to-hide-connections-between-accounts?rq=1 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142519/can-an-account-be-manually-unassociated-from-my-network-profile. Possible dupe of the latter.

Comment: @HDE226868 - I was just about to edit the first link into the question...

Comment: @HDE226868 - i'm guessing this may be a duplicate of the second link...