# What is Anonymous answering / answers

Tags: support, posting

Recently, I came through a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703783/reversing-simple-javascript-user-agent-logic) answered by **Anonymous**. First I thought it as some account and I found lo link with the name. Below is the screenshot;

[image: Screenshot]

What are Anonymous postings?

Comment: ....Cowards....

Comment: @j08691 Well spoken jay-zero-eight-six.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely this is a case where the original author of the post asked to have the post disassociated with his account.

Post dissociation is a right that every post author has under the CC-by-SA license.

Comment: How is a post dissociated? Via flags? Or is there an automated option?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: See [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732)

Comment: Does someone have some confirmation on the "...deleted his account or..." part?, I have seen these and I believe they become faded unlinked userIDs (not "Anonymous"). Someone correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @ajax333221 poking now to see if that has changed. You're correct, (RPG at least, still uses anonID)

Comment: @waxeagle It has changed in the opposite direction: userID format is used since mid-2011. The screenshot predates this change.