# How to permanently delete my question from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I want my question to be deleted permanently from Stack Overflow for some reasons. I have deleted the question, but when searching in Google, it is still showing up. I don't have a reputation over 10,000 to delete. But I want it to be deleted from my account. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Yes, TimeTravelingBobby is right... Even if the page is entirely deleted from the SO servers, Google will still have its cache that can be used to see the page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stack Exchange does not permanently delete questions from the database.

I have a hunch you are confused between deletion and closure. The difference between closure and deletion:

- A closed question can be seen by all users. It can be voted on but not answered. A closed question can be reopened.
- A deleted question can be seen by users with 10.000 reputation or more. It can not be voted on or answered.  It can be undeleted.
- A permanently deleted question is rare. It requires action of the developers and was only done in the earlier days of the network. As far as I know there is no way to reverse this (other than retyping the question).

Comment: As u have more than enough reputation can u help me in doing that if i gave the link?

Comment: I can delete a closed question, but I cannot permanently delete a question. But please give the link.

Comment: I have already deleted the question.but that is only voluntarly delete.any way this is the linkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098642/how-to-load-my-sidemenu-from-with-in-the-viewcontroller

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated. If OP is trying to remove data completely there is now a way to [redact a revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274274/143909).

Comment: This is super outdated. According to GDPR, there must be a way to disconnect an identity from content (either by fully deleting, not fake deleting, or by fully anonymizing).

Comment: @DanielW. There is, it's called [disassociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/461068) and it's an entirely separate process from deletion, though the two can easily be combined.

Answer (score 14):

How recently did you delete the question?

Once a question is deleted it will take a little while for Google's reindexing of the site to notice and remove the **cached** copy from search results.

Google is very good at adding new content, removing old content takes a little longer.

Answer (score 10):

If the problem is that the content is associated with you then you can email the team asking to disassociate the question from your account, so it appears to be from some anonymous user instead.

Otherwise (if the contents are the problem) you can ask for permanent removal as suggested in other answers, but the team is not obliged to do that. Once you submit something, it's no longer really yours.