# Marking a question as "inactive"

Tags: support, questions

I just want to keep my question alive so that it's comment and answer can help others, but want to make it inactive so that I won't receive any comments from any other user since I have got the required answer.

Please anyone let me know how to do this.

Comment: I don't really understand why you'd want to do this. Accept an answer if your question has been resolved, that way people know you're not still looking for something else. What more do you need/want?

Comment: What if someone in future wants to ask you how did you solve that problem?

Comment: @Mat... what if I have asked multiple questions in different ways to resolve same issue, but I have accepted answer for one question but both the questions have good collection of research and comments so that can help other user, so if I accept answer for one question then that will get close but for other question for which I haven't accepted answer will continue to get the comments and solution but I just want to make that inactive so that I won't receive any answer for it and it will also help other users too.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing that - they should have been marked as duplicates of the best set out question, or if some of the answers are particularly good.

Comment: You might rephrase this as a feature request: "Allow me to filter notices from specific questions of mine".  That is, nothing changes except that comments from that Q, and its answers, don't show in your inbox. IMO, it would be most unsporting to do something like that, though.

Comment: Note you can flag/vote to close your own question as a duplicate, I think that would be the way forward now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The questions are always alive (unless deleted) and the users (and guests alike) can read them. By making the question inactive (or as it is known as **locked**); you are restricting others from asking any doubts they might have. Since you've already got the required answer on that question; and you don't want notifications of any activity; you can ask the mods to remove your [link to the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/212576).

However, there are no other methods to mark a post as inactive as far as I know.

---

After reading your [recent comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198070/marking-a-question-as-inactive/198072#comment627320_198070), I think you are confusing Stack Exchange sites with forums. If you mark an answer to be selected, it does NOT mean that the post is inactive or that no one else can answer it. The post is still very much alive and active. Marking an answer as selected just shows other users what you (or the OP) followed to solve the specific problems they were having.

If some other user (at a later date) thinks that the problem can be solved in more efficient way (or not), they can suggest an answer as well.

Comment: @hjpotter92.. thanks for proper explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A question can be *protected*, which prevents new users from answering it, or it can be *locked*, which prevents anybody from commenting/answer/editing/voting on the question.

You can ask a moderator to have your question protected or locked, by flagging your question and using the option "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)", but in general this is reserved for situations where the amount of comments/answers on a question is very large.

Comment: @Mat Because comments already need atleast 50 rep.