# Mention post disassociation in the help center and contact form

Tags: feature-request, users, help-center, creative-commons, contact

As per §4.a of the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) that all Stack Exchange posts are under,

> upon notice from any Licensor [Stack Exchange] must, to the extent practicable, remove from the Collection any credit as required by Section 4(c), as requested.

The most obvious way for a contributor to do that is to flag their own post. This is what is mentioned by [the Meta.SO post on the subject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki); I couldn't find any mention in the help center. This transmits the request to moderators, who have no way to honor it and must pass on the request to Stack Exchange staff.

It would be more direct if content disassociation requests went directly to Stack Exchange staff, via the [contact form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). Please mention content credit removal in the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) — possibly under [What is the license for the content I post?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/licensing)

Comment: While I'm at it, moderators also get requests to delete a revision (e.g. containing private information), which they must transmit to Stack Exchange staff. This too would be better handled via the contact form.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree on eliminating the middle folk here.

Comment: Another improvement in such cases would be a dev flag system that would allow us mods to flag such posts for SE attention without having to ping someone in chat or write an email

Comment: Couldn't this be made a fully automated process in the first place? Why not make it as easy to reach as the CW checkbox?

Comment: @probablyPekka the downside of that is that it lets abusive users cover their tracks. Furthermore disassociated posts don't count towards the bans since they are effectively removed from the account.

Comment: @Pëkka: Yep! There is no downside to it either if it is properly implemented and even if that is "too difficult", the users would be caught sooner or later. In my opinion, the best would be to make it automatic rather than handled by SE staff. I will post a feature request about that since otherwise you need be very careful about post disassociation requests. [I got a one-month long ban without prior warning after about five such cases with gaps among them](http://expertflow.wordpress.com/2014/08/10/stack-exchange-and-license-issues/). I was even told, next time my account would be deleted.

Answer (score -2):

If you wanted to frame it as a legal obligation, StackExchange could be nasty and tell you that you already have a way to remove your name: deleting your account.

Comment: They could, but as far as I can tell they would be incorrect in so doing. The license allows, and SE currently permits, disassociation with any given content desired without prejudice to any other.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, where is "without prejudice to any other" written?

Comment: "any" credit, not "all" credit, and "as requested", not "when a request is received".

Comment: @NathanTuggy, "A" doesn't mean "A and only A", plus it says "from the Collection" which according to the OP applies to the question hence it says nothing on the others, plus it says "to the extent practicable" and if there is no software feature to do it then it's arguably not practicable.