# Proposal against power abuse on stack sites and a more democratic voting system

Tags: feature-request, moderation, abuse, rules

Stack Exchange sites are fantastic and very useful. I have been using them for years but in the last time the management is getting bad, moderators abusing power, deleting posts and comments just because they can and they think so. The fact that some people are moderators does not mean that their judgement is absolute. They can delete posts and comment at their will and sometime you get even persecuted by same moderator. I really find this offending, no respect and not good education. It is against any rule of democracy and freedom of speech and expression.
So I am proposing this changes, hoping that will limit the abuse on stacksites:

- Only automatic post/comment delete
- Post/comment should be automatically deleted if it has more then 10 negative down-votes (-10)
- Make mandatory comment if a post is down-voted
- Automatize as many process as possible

I do not want stack-sites to became the centre of control of little bunch of persons. It should be free of any dictator abuse. It should be in control of all community.

Comment: "Post/comment should be automatically deleted if it has more then 10 negative down-votes (-10)" -- there are no comment downvotes. If you mean flags, that threshold is way too high. Also, this would delete many meta posts that shouldn't be deleted (also, it would delete this meta post). Also, some SO questions would be deleted without the asker having a chance to react. Others would be deleted way later than they should be.

Comment: "Post/comment should be automatically deleted if it has any bad word (dirty words)" - Why? I love cocks (roosters), tits (... is there a synonym?), craps (the game), boobies (they don't live where I do, but they do look cool)...

Comment: Yes I meant flags. And what then leave deletion to control of some?

Comment: Yes delete post if they are attacking some one with offending words

Comment: "Make mandatory comment if a post is down-voted" -- suggested many times before. Always rejected. You can't force people to leave _useful_ comments. Also, frequently, at least for questions, the reason is blindingly obvious. Learn to search, please.

Comment: I suggest that you first take your proposals one by one and look whether anything like it has been proposed or even implemented already and what the reaction was. If anything remains, really think it through and then post it as a single feature request.

Comment: Are you offended by cute tiny birds with yellow breasts and lovely voice?

Comment: I am making some proposal. It anyone has better idea just post it. What can we do to make this sites better ?

Comment: @JanDvorak you are totally out of scope. if I write "you're a idiot" to someone you think this is not offending?

Comment: @albanx now what if someone starts their answer with "I'm an idiot" - will you nuke the answer from orbit?

Comment: Same with "This is a dumb/stupid question"

Comment: "This is a dumb/stupid question" of course is offending.

Comment: @albanx so, would you nuke any question about which their asker states it's dumb or stupid? That's a stupid move.

Comment: I repeat I made some proposals if you have better suggestions just post they, I will edit my question

Comment: I cannot delete my own question, this could be a good point.

Comment: You cannot delete your question now because other users have invested their time editing it, reading it and answering it. One user cannot delete the question and waste the effort all the other users invested on that post.

Comment: I see way too many "Offensive" flags for "What an idiot", when the commenter is referring to *themselves*.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Don't forget the offensive flags for self-deprecating phrases like "Stupid question, but have you tried X to see if it makes this better?" In that case, I can understand non-native English speakers reading that the wrong way.

Comment: @BradLarson Definitely agreed

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion I cannot delete an question now because other users have invested their time editing it, reading it... I agree it make sense, but moderators can delete question, so they can trash all user time and efforts? Is this correct for the users?

Comment: No, it isn't correct, that is why all moderator actions are reversible, nothing is hard deletion. As Flexo mentioned in my post, you can challenge any moderator decision using the correct channels. As for you deleting your own post, you can't delete it now because it is a community effort. You can dissociate the post from your account, that option stays open, so that our contributions remain intact. However, dissociation is permanent, you can't get the post linked back to your account again http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225997/245167. The system is designed to be fair...and it is.

Comment: You are a good user, you have highly upvoted answers on SO. Your posts are clear and well-written, I fail to understand why are you giving up on proper channels? Constructively start a discussion, I do it too, and it always helps me. Meta sites are a very good place for discussions. So are public chat rooms like the Tavern on MSE, where all of us from different SE networks, devs, cms are present.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion since I discover SO I really like it, clear, simple, fast and good community helping each other. BUT look what happen here just today: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/how-secure-is-aes-256/11461?noredirect=1#comment46789_11461, my answer was deleted after 1 year. it has got 2 downvotes but also 2 upvotes and I loose my points there just because the mikeazo moderator wake up suddenly and decide to consider that as comment. And I had post that answer before NSA spy scandals was discover proving the truth of that answer. I try to contact even via chat by no reply

Comment: I don't see a comment, did mod convert to a comment or did mod delete it? I am seeking help in this in the Tavern, if you want, you can join us there..http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta

Comment: I checked with Shog, can you please flag using "others" option and ask for a mod review for undeletion as it doesn't appear to be a comment   http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2641699#2641699

Comment: Your post has been undeleted :)

Comment: Hey brother, another that some in power had tried to repress because of our opinions *Hive Five* :)

Comment: In other words, you want Stack Overflow to become Yahoo Answers.

Comment: @albanx without moderation that's exactly what SO will become.

Comment: @ShadowWizard moderators should look at other things rather than " not I do not like you question" or "what so upvote for this stupid question" or " I do not like this question let's close", question are made for answer and not for being blamed by moderators and stupid users

Answer (score 22):

> The fact that some people are moderators does not mean that their judgement is absolute.

Moderation privileges are gained by community members by participation in the system and by diamond moderators who are elected/appointed. This is according to the [Theory of Moderation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/). Each one of us starts from one rep, and gradually progresses and learns how to participate in moderating and cleaning the sites; this is required because over time, a lot of noise tends to accumulate.

> It is against any rule of democracy and freedom of speech and expression.

The most important privilege is unlocked at 5 rep, which gives you a chance to participate in Meta, and discuss with the community in cases where you want to know the reason behind a certain action.

Meta participation helps us learn about the community. Many users discuss [disputed audits/reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits), [disputed flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-flags), [closed questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close-reasons), [deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deleted-questions?sort=newest&pageSize=15) over there. The community helps you understand the reasons, and many posts get undeleted and reopened as a result of Meta effect.

Understand that we are all humans, including moderators, and sometimes due to the huge volume of flags they handle on high-traffic sites like Stack Overflow, they may make mistakes too. Come to Meta and constructively open a channel for discussion, the community will always help you.

And finally, making comments mandatory for downvotes [has been discussed numerous times, and the request has always been declined.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

As for your proposed changes, comments are second-class citizens, they can be deleted any time, use them only to ask for clarifications. Don't engage with any user in arguments, walk away. Only use comments for content related to the post. Flagging is a privilege unlocked at 15 rep, [flag any comment you think is too chatty, offensive or rude, it will eventually be removed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237980/245167)

Apart from posting on Meta, for quick discussions with community members to discuss the problems you face, or receive immediate feedback, chat is a very good option too. You can visit chatrooms like the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and ask for advice any time you want. The privilege "talk in chat" is unlocked at 20 rep.

As [Flexo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/153020/flexo) [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243317/proposal-against-power-abuse-on-stack-sites-and-a-more-democratic-voting-system/243322?noredirect=1#comment795265_243322):

> Provided you use the correct channels to do so you can challenge any moderator or community decision. That's not to say anyone will agree with you, but with the exception of personal information the whole moderation process is very open and democratic.

Comment: A repeating "mistake" is an abuse

Comment: [Did you open then link to the latest questions on Meta and see?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) Everyday, lots of issues get discussed and resolved. This is how democracy works. Do you have any questions/answers which you think is incorrectly closed/deleted?

Comment: How can you discuss with someone that deletes your comments? I agree one should discuss but if some one deletes post and even comments , where is the discussion? I hope you understand why I open this post

Comment: Only employees and elected moderators can delete you comments, no one else. If someone has deleted your posts with the comments, you should go and discuss why that was done on Meta or [chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta). Other users will provide you screenshot of the deleted posts for continuing the discussion constructively [like this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276443/why-was-this-question-deleted-so-quickly)

Comment: [It happens all the time to a lot of users,](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) so yes, I understand @albanx. But once you learn to use the sites and it's features, you will do well :)

Comment: @albanx provided you use the correct channels to do so you can challenge any moderator or community decision. That's not to say anyone will agree with you, but with the exception of personal information the whole moderation process is very open and democratic.

Comment: “Only employees and elected moderators can delete you comments, no one else.” – That’s not exactly correct. If a comment accumulates sufficiently many flags, it gets deleted automatically (see [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17364/255554)).

Answer (score 13):

> moderators abusing power, deleting posts and comments just because they can and they think so

> sometime you get even persecuted by same moderator

Don't you think that's quite an extreme accusation to make without any evidence or argument whatsoever?

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that you're talking about [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/13072/7473). Your concerns seem to be wildly off-base here. First of all, the reason for deletion of some comments has been clearly stated:

> @albanx, if you'd like to have an open-ended discussion, please feel free to use the chat. This area is for asking questions that can be answered. Please review the guidance in the site tour: mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour. This is not an area for [no true scotsman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) arguments.

In fact, the moderator who left this comment was quite generous. You can't expect comments to be permanent; they're "second-class citizens," and they can be deleted at any time, even without notice.

> It is against any rule of democracy and freedom of speech and expression

To quote xkcd, "The right to free speech means the government can't arrest you for what you say. It doesn't mean that anyone *else* has to listen to your bulls**t, or host you while you share it."

The fact that it is *legal* for you to post comments here doesn't make it *illegal* for us to delete them if they are rude, offensive, non-constructive, too chatty, or for any other reason. Stack Exchange sites are community-run: The community as a whole decides what content is appropriate, not just you.

> - Only automatic post/comment delete
> - Post/comment should be automatically deleted if it has more then 10 negative down-votes (-10)
>     Automatize as many process as possible

... oh dear. I... don't even know how I can react to this.

Okay, first of all, your question and other valuable meta questions and answers would be deleted just because other people disagree with them. And perfectly valid questions on, say, Stack Overflow, with perfectly valid answers, would also get deleted, just because they're a little low in quality. (Also, comments don't have downvotes.)

But more importantly, almost *no* stuff that *should* be deleted would get deleted. Out of the 3701 posts on [PPCG](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), only **seventeen** of them are voted -10 or below. (Mostly spam or offensive posts, where a spam or offensive/abusive flag gives an extra downvote.) And there are a **total of 2319** deleted posts voted +0 or above.

Many positively voted posts get deleted too, for a wide variety of reasons. Votes are not a method of saying "I believe this post should {stay on the site / go away}," and you can't try to make them that.

> Make mandatory comment if a post is down-voted

Yeah, this has been discussed to *death*.

*downvotes post*
*posts comment: "I like coooookies"*

> It should be in control of all community.

And it is indeed. Moderators are elected directly by the community. You gain [privileges](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) as you earn reputation, and a user with the "trusted user" privilege can actually do most of the things that moderators do anyway. Your [per-site meta](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/) is a perfect place to discuss every aspect of the site, or bring up complaints or requests.

Comment: Yes because that is my second question about. That guy there delete my first question with no reason, now you read the comment in the second question. I even reply to that comment but he deletes every reply I give. So I am not going to talk on chat with someone that deletes my comments and posts.

Comment: And who judge to decide if something I am saying is a bulls***t?

Comment: @albanx You keep saying "with no reason." I see a comment there that explains exactly what the reason is. If you wish to discuss this further, I recommend doing it on the per-site meta (but make sure you actually have a question, and not just a rant).

Comment: @albanx The community is to judge that, of course. If we don't want it, we have the ability to get rid of it, and that does not violate free speech in any way.

Comment: yes the community but not a single person

Comment: @albanx Moderators are trusted members of the community. Other moderators can undelete comments if necessary, but it rarely is. Again, comments are very transient, and you can't expect them to stay there forever.

Comment: and that does not mean that a moderator can do every thing he want, yes comments are very transient, but not for 5 seconds

Comment: @albanx You should probably bring this up on a meta post on your own site, as suggested in a previous comment. We don't know enough about the specific situation to accurately respond to your statements and questions.

Comment: I do want to discuss on my specific case, I just want to propose or find a way to make the system more fair and equal for all.

Comment: *I do not want*

Comment: albanx - of the folks involved with that specific question, only one is a moderator on Mechanics. I'm not seeing anything done that is power abuse, and in fact the 2 down votes you got were explained pretty quickly by me and Paulster.

Comment: @RoryAlso I am not referring to you or Paulster, indeed I just want to say thank you to you for the polite discussion. the problem are not the downvotes (they are welcome), but question and comment deletion.

Answer (score 6):

A lot of moderation - i.e. placing questions on hold are done by community members with sufficient reputation -  members to put a question 'on hold' or to 'reopen' as an example.  Those without sufficient reputation can flag answers and questions that are off-topic, don't show enough prior research and the like.

As I have learned, comments are '3rd class citizens' and can be deleted by a moderator, or by community flagging.  If you see something offensive - flag it.

As for comments on downvotes, this has been discussed many times, you'd get comments like `GYVVKBibubflrbfenfnefne` just to get around that condition - so the person being downvoted is still none the wiser. Voting is anonymous, for one thing this can stop the possibility of 'revenge voting'.

Many of the processes are automated. For a significant part, the community does have considerable control in the sites.

Comment: Being short is a pretty good heuristic, but not an a-priori reason to downvote/closevote a question.

Comment: I agree with you. Comment like GYVVKBibubflrbfenfnefne will be flag by users and automatically deleted

Comment: @albanx and, what you are left with is a downvote without comment

Comment: @JanDvorak I am sure that there are ways to make the stack system better. I really have doubt on anonymous downvotes. Afraid from revenge?

Answer (score 2):

I think a little introspection might help you understand the issue here. Of course this is meta so the flow of things is a little bit different, but lets look at the ramifications of your suggestion:

> Post/comment should be automatically deleted if it has more then 10 negative down-votes (-10)

As it stands right now this very post is at -29 (+1/-30). So I put it do you: given your suggested rule structure your post would long ago have been auto-deleted. Is that what you think should have happened to it? Would you like for your idea to be swept under the rug based on (un)popular consensus? Wouldn't that bother you more than having the issue discussed and the reasons why the system doesn't work like that explained?

Personally, I hang around Stack Exchange sites specifically because they ARE moderated. The signal to noise ratio on the main sites is much higher here than on most Internet forums guided by raw popularity.

Comment: I just proposed some ideas but they are not gold ones, better can be find. the problem of SO is that in the last years it getting very negative, not any more a helping community but just user attacking other users look what happen yesterday (again):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021239/part-of-ajax-responsetext?noredirect=1#comment42569258_27021239

Comment: @albanx It doesn't look like just a case of needing to find a better solution, it looks like a case that you have completely mis-diagnosed the problem. You appear to be fighting the platform rather than working with it. You'll have a much better experience if you take the time to learn it's strengths then help contribute to keeping it focused on those things rather than pulling it toward a least-common-denominator type approach (which is what this meta post suggests).