# How can I contact Stack Overflow support?

Tags: support, contact

How can I contact someone on stackoverflow.com to check my post history?(I think I uploaded a question on a certain date but it is shown as being uploaded yesterday, I did try deleting it more than one time). I need to contact someone who can help me with post history issues.

Comment: Is this your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32499709/galton-box-bean-machine-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that your question will be removed. It has an accepted and upvoted answer. When you signed up to Stack Exchange you agreed to the [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal). One of those terms is:

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You.

You do, however, have the option of having a post [disassociated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki) from your account. This anonymizes the post and removes your name from it. You can do so by flagging the post and requesting disassociation or by using the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of every page and describing your request completely (providing links to the appropriate posts).

Comment: I did not notice the contact us button at the bottom of the page till now.