# A new reputation value based on Open Source Software (OSS) financial support

Tags: feature-request, reputation

From time to time I financially support Open Source Software (OSS) projects.

For example, I downloaded Ubuntu 16.10 and made standard $15 donation. And now I would like to have that support visible on SO, next to my reputation points.

I would be more willing to answer "read the manual" questions knowing that the author at least financially supports OSS.

Everybody knows that some OSS projects need financial support. Maybe SO could help somehow.

---

> No, the sole influencer of whether and how quickly a question is considered for answering should be its quality and not a property of its asker.

So the reputation bounty feature should be removed?

> So you are more willing to answer badly researched questions since the user supports an open source project?

yes. many people already stopped contributing to SO because of lack of good questions. There was a lot of discussions about this in last 6 months.

> And what to think about users that live in countries where they don't earn as much as you do? Should we ignore them just because they can't contribute financially to such projects?

they can do better research. and also gain from OSS projects financed by lazy guys from richer countries

> "many people already stopped contributing to SO because of lack of good questions", so you propose to make the problem worse? You say you actually want that questions now.

These questions are already on SO and nothing stops them now. Why do you assume that my proposal would make the problem worse? Knowing that poor quality question won't be answered without financial OSS support, should motivate to do better research. Anyway, hard to guess what an impact might be without an experiment.

Comment: Downvotes here only indicate disagreement, rather than post quality. People disagreeing with you is demotivating?

Comment: @M.A.R. not disagreement, but I've lost 40 rep points, and this looks as I did something really bad. that kind of down votes number should get an offensive or racist post. If my post is so offensive to moderators then allow me to delete it.

Comment: Setting aside issues of quality, why would those who donate to OSS get more recognition than those actively developing it?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara the donations go to people who actively develop OSS

Comment: Besides anything else this would be pretty irrelevant and pointless on most sites.

Comment: When a question has answers on it, that have upvotes, the question typically will not be deleted - that would invalidate all those votes. Once you post content, you don't really have the right to delete it - have a look at the agreement you signed up to

Comment: @Servy I didn't licensed my name to SE. So the post must be deleted or my name removed the for post and comments https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_be_forgotten

Comment: Use the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of every page on this site to ask for your username to be disassociated from this post. See [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki)

Comment: You're drawing *way* more attention to your post by constantly vandalizing it than if you'd just done nothing.  If you're actually worried about how this question will affect other's views of you, you're only making it that much worse for yourself.

Comment: **THIS IS SPAM**

Answer (score 14):

No, ideally the sole influencer of whether and how quickly a question is considered for answering should be its quality and not a property of its asker.

You can of course offer a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), if you wish to advertise the existence of your question, but the quality of your question will still influence whether and how quickly it is considered for answering.

Comment: So reputation bounty feature should be removed?

Comment: @GregDan Ideally a bounty should be placed on a good question that someone considers valuable to be answered. If a bad question gets a bounty, it still should not be answered, and really bad bounties questions still got closed by moderator intervention.

Answer (score 10):

The quality and content of the question, as well as the effort the asker makes are considerations for how quickly and comprehensively a question is answered, rather than the actions of the asker (however noble they may be).

Additionally, there is potential for people being pressured into donating into these projects in return for an answer - could be abused as an unfair leverage. This could be made worse if the asker is not in a position to even consider donating.

Answer (score 9):

For the Q/A, it doesn't matter who the user is who asks or answers the question: it is about the content.

> I would be more willing to answer RTFM questions knowing that the author at least financially supports OSS.

So you are more willing to answer badly researched questions since the user supports an open source project? Since when did we trade quality for money? And what to think about users that live in countries where they don't earn as much as you do? Should we ignore them just because they can't contribute financially to such projects?

Comment: "So you are more willing to answer badly researched questions since the user supports an open source project?" yes. many people already stopped contributing to SO because of lack of good questions. There was a lot of discussions about this in last 6 months.

Comment: "Should we ignore them just because they can't contribute financially to such projects?" they can do better research. and also gain from OSS projects financed by lazy guys from richer countries.

Comment: @GregDan "many people already stopped contributing to SO because of lack of good questions", so you propose to make the problem worse? You say you actually want that questions now...

Comment: "You say you actually want that questions now" these questions are already on SO and nothing stops them now. Why do you assume that my proposal would make the problem worse? Knowing that poor quality question won't be answered without financial OSS support, should motivate to do better research.