# Is there any way for diamond moderators to suspend a user without sending a moderator message?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, account-suspension

I was looking at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334169/why-was-my-account-suspended) (now deleted) and the user claims to have not received any kind of message about their suspension. (I'm not interested in this specific case, just giving the example that spawned the question).

As far as I know, that is not possible. So, just to reinforce that so I can be confident in answering future cases like this:

Is there any way to suspend a user without sending a mod message?

Do automatic suspensions come with a message?

Comment: Maybe community moderators (employees) can do this, I don't know for sure.

Comment: In TL, a SO mod could maybe answer if he seen the mod message for that user, as they are supposed to be CC for them

Comment: I think automated/manually issued network-wide suspensions don't send messages - but everything else does... you might want to also refer to my comment on that post - seems to be a mix up of terminology (and potentially mis-remembering going on): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334169/why-was-my-account-suspended#comment1092302_334169

Comment: @JonClements Sure, I did see that. I'm less interested in this specific case as being able to say "moderators cannot suspend a user without sending a moderator message" in general in the future.

Comment: Just FYI, it was later determined in comments that the user was lying when they said they didn't receive a moderator message; they had in fact replied to it before posting that question.

Answer (score 18):

No there isn't. In fact there's no pathway to suspend outside the mod message menu.

Suspensions are always accompanied by a mod message.

Considering the intention of a mod message is for problem behavior to be corrected - we have no reason to suspend someone without telling them why

Comment: "No. It's literally impossible, even for CMs... The only exception is a network-wide suspension. – Catija♦ 50 secs ago" What is the exception about network-wide suspension?

Comment: I feel like that's a moot point, @ankii. . . Diamond mods can't suspend a user network-wide, and in this case said user isn't suspended network-wide anyway, so that (edge) case doesn't apply here. . . But in the case of a network-wide suspension, for what it's worth, presumably *many* per-site suspensions have preceded it, and dialogues have been attempted (and, presumably, failed), and arguably the user doesn't deserve much of a mod message with the suspension because they're past the point of . . . well . . . trying to fix their behavior.

Answer (score 17):

There is a way that accounts can be suspended without sending a moderator message.

If an account is deleted or destroyed using two specific options (with either spamming or "no longer welcome to participate" marked as the reason for the deletion), the system will automatically levy a 365-day suspension at the same time the account is removed, with no corresponding moderator message. Normally, this automatic suspension isn't visible to anyone, so this doesn't matter...

...unless the user recreates the deleted account, in which case the system will automatically "reinstate" this suspension, as part of an automated process to reinstate suspensions against accounts in case the user tries to delete and recreate their account to avoid it. This can lead to an [apparent case where no moderator message is sent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309723/377214).

Additionally, *chat* suspensions don't carry a moderator message, as that's an entirely separate mechanism.

Other than these cases, and the case of network-wide suspensions pointed out by Catija on a deleted answer here, all site suspensions do indeed carry a moderator message with them.

Answer (score 6):

There used to be one, but after I used it back in 2011 (or 2012), it was disabled. It's *compulsory* to send a message when suspending a user.

[Avoid the Streisand Effect - be clear about the reason when suspending an account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-accoun/23548#23548)