# Delete embarrassing posts from long time ago?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[It says here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) that one is not allowed to delete their own post when it has already been answered and that answer got upvoted, or when there have been more than 1 answers.

This makes me wonder: Is there a way to get rid of embarrassing questions you asked in the past, that would be bad for your reputation if people found out which person (in the real world) your account belongs to. (I mean: if people found out that your name John Doe is linked to your account user123466).

- Are we allowed to delete questions in that case?
- Or is there another option?

Answer (score 12):

You can't delete it, but you can have it dissociated from your account.

You do this by sending Stack Exchange a request using the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page.
There may still be a trail in archiving services like the Wayback Machine; that can't really be avoided.

Account dissociation is also discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/168333) as a FAQ.

Comment: Does this remove any trail? (so long as a third party hasn't stored the link of course) How do we do this?

Comment: @user38207 any trail in the live sites, yes.

Comment: @user38207 comments though maintain their original username.

Comment: @Fermiparadox Good point, I didn't realize that. Fortunately comments can easily be deleted, unless the post is locked.

Comment: @S.L.Barth yes, self-comments can be deleted. If others `@ping` someone though the username will remain as is, even if the user being pinged changes his name later on.

Comment: @Fermiparadox At that point, it would not be clear if the pinged user is the user who wrote the embarrassing post or a random user who commented, and then deleted the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can request to dissociate - but I think there's a somewhat simpler pair of options.

Firstly - you can use an alternate account, just make sure you keep it active long enough to pick an answer. Unless there's interaction between your main account and alternate, it should be fine.

Secondly, well, think before you post anything that can be embarassing.

In *theory* if there won't be a substantial loss of reputation for the users involved, and you asked nicely a mod may choose, at their discretion to delete it.  But stuff not posted, or stuff well thought up so its not embarassing is always welcome.