# My view on an answer has changed dramatically but it is locked - who can help?

Tags: support, locked-questions, locked, historical-lock

[One of my most popular answers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/116746/9444) is definitely outdated from my understanding today. I'd like to either add a disclaimer to the top, delete it, or remove my name from it. However, it is closed and locked.

Who can help?

Comment: If you cannot flag, maybe you could visit chat and ask one of the site's mods to intervene and temporarily unlock it?

Comment: @Mari-LouA that would undermine the purpose of historical lock. Doubt mods will do it. (It's kind of "rewriting history" which isn't a good idea.)

Comment: @Shadow9 if the OP particularly feels that the answer needs to be updated  (by adding the date in the disclaimer) because since 2008 they have reviewed the situation, would that be so wrong? It's not a programming question where visitors would necessarily assume that the answer to be outdated.

Comment: @Mari-LouA With an on-topic question, that would not be a problem. Questions which are historically locked should be lucky they even survived.

Comment: seems like disassociation is your way to go here. Mast's answer covers the particulars of that.

Comment: @Magisch still, would need a valid reason. Dis-associating takes expensive CM time, so shouldn't be done on a whim. Just "I don't want" won't fit.

Comment: @Shadow9 iirc disassociation is a right for users, so it'll definitely happen even if for no reason, but may take time.

Comment: @Magisch Isn't one of the purposes for historically locking questions to say that the answers were, at the time, highly upvoted and valid but the question was later viewed to be off-topic? Today, those answers survive and continue to "help" visitors. However, if, for whatever reason, one answer contains false information or the author wishes to revise their answer it should not be such a complicated procedure. Otherwise, wouldn't deletion be the more sensible option rather than removing one's name?

Comment: @Mari-LouA far as I know, the rationale for historical locks is along those lines, yeah. It probably wouldn't hurt to raise a flag, but you can't directly edit it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Considering it's [historically locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for), the question and answers shouldn't be updated. That banner shows the content should be taken with a grain of salt already, so I wouldn't feel obligated to get the content adjusted.

If you want to remove your name from it, you can request disassociation of the specific post. That's explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/269301). Do keep in mind (as in part pointed out by the answer in the link) it's a drastic measure and has side-effects you may not have considered.

To quote:

> #### So how do I remove my name from a post?
>
> If you would like to have your name dissociated from one of your posts, you can request we do so by clicking on the *Contact* link at the bottom of the respective page. Your username will no longer be linked, the username [will be shown as "anon"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290627), and you will no longer earn any reputation from the post. All reputation you had previously gained/lost from the post [including bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311966/349538) will also be reversed, and [badges you earned from the post may be revoked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348351/what-happens-in-terms-of-rep-when-dissociating-a-question-from-my-account/348352?noredirect=1#comment468678_348352)

Comment: sad, that that is the option I have to chose.