# Make it easier to delete profile from all sites

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, network-profile

Thanks to the recent behaviour of SE, I have come to the conclusion I have no desire to remain part of it in any way shape or form, and have had to spend far more time than seems reasonable to delete (or rather schedule for deletion) my account on each site. Although now complete, so my request is unnecessary for me, in the interest of considering others can there be a way to delete a profile on all sites with a single click?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336000/users-need-to-be-able-to-remove-themselves-and-all-their-data-from-the-site

Comment: @rene hopefully if you ever decide to leave by then they'd have implemented a single-click option. Id be very pleased to have saved you some time.

Comment: I probably write a userscript, then at least I go out with a bang

Comment: Re the related q, I'm really only asking for a quicker way for anyone else to delete multiple accounts at once, not for a complete data scrub. I was actually surprised that the topic hadn't been raised before (as far as I could see)

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit stunned by no earlier requests as well. That one was the best I could find and is easily "expanded" to the network profile level.

Comment: One you [get the hang of the controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt7nO.jpg) it goes faster.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Improve the user self-deletion process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156559/improve-the-user-self-deletion-process).  In particular: "The user clicks a "delete profile" button in his profile. There should be a way to indicate if you want to delete all profiles on all SE sites, only on this site and a way to select multiple sites from a list where the profile should be deleted."

Comment: @PolyGeo it definitely includes my suggestion, and the top answer does as well, but the package as a whole is larger than my single-item suggestion. However feel free to mark as a duplicate or whatever the equivalent is on meta - although I'm not sure what sort of impact that would have regarding whether the requested feature would be evaluated?

Comment: Couldn't you file a GDPR request? Just search for an appropriate template, fill it out and email it to them. That way, they also have to comply with not keeping any PII records on you.

Comment: The GDPR request which is probably valid for the whole company and therefore for all accounts sounds like a convenient bypass if you live in Europe for the time until this feature request is implemented.

Comment: My first thought was leaving. But then I decided to [fight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335068/bye-stack-exchange-im-done-coerced-speech-is-incompatible-with-freedom/337454#337454) them.