# How to delete my own question to prevent new comments and answers?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete, post-disassociation

I have recently asked a question where I wanted to scrape data from Google maps, but it turns out it's ethically wrong. I would have liked to delete my question, but as other people have spent time on it, I am not allowed to delete it.

I would like to delete the question now, so nobody can comment/answer the question.

Comment: FYI if this is the question in question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62590307/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-google-maps-location-from-the-name-of-the-landmark You can delete that, the answer needs at least a score of +1 to prevent deletion.

Comment: I've casted the final close vote, so no new answers can be added. It is still possible that users vote / comment on it. It will self-delete in 10 days now, unless the answers gets upvoted or accepted. Keep in mind that deleting negative scored questions can have impact on your ability to ask new questions. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583 for info on that situation.

Comment: Closing a question doesn't prevent people from voting on it.

Comment: See this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa)

Answer (score 1):

You need 250 reputation to view and cast close votes on your own posts.  Also, closing a question does not prevent people from commenting (see [Discord.js: command is not working on the mobile app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350099/discord-js-command-is-not-working-on-the-mobile-app), you will still see the "Add Comment" button) or casting votes on it.

Answer (score 1):

To delete [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62590307/4947898) question, you have two effective options:

1. **If you are in a hurry**, flag this question for a moderator intervention explaining your reason. A moderator might delete it, but it is entirely their decision.
2. **If you are not in a hurry**, wait for 9 days while hoping that the question remains closed with a negative score and the answer does not reach a positive score. Also, do not accept that answer.