# Can an answered question be anonymized because it can't be deleted?

Tags: feature-request, support

> You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and
> effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.

The situation is as follows:

1. A question has a positive record and an answer only upvoted by the question author.
2. The question author doesn't want anyone else to know that they asked this question, but they can't delete it.

Is there any solution for this? For example, can I flag the question and let an administrator or moderator change the author to *Community*?

Comment: That is way down mentioned in the FAQ on How does deleting works: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that in the paragraph *If I flag my post with a request to delete it, what will happen?*

Comment: [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/295232) is probably more to the point.