# How should I handle my low-quality questions?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I have asked some questions that have been voted down. Now I think it is not a good question and I want to delete it. But sometimes it tells me that a user answered this question which took the user's time, so I could not delete the question.

I understand. People take time to read and answer the question. If I deleted the question, I will waste other people's time and patience. But on the other side, the question is low quality and I do not think it could help others in the future, so what is the better way to treat these questions?

Comment: If you are aware that it is low quality, why not edit it into something that's high quality? Take care to keep the meaning the same so the existing answers aren't invalidated.

Comment: @RobertLongson That sounds like the start of an answer.

Comment: Deleting low quality questions, instead of improving them, is a guaranteed way to eventually become question banned.  All questions are considered when determine if your questions have reach the threshold to become question banned even deleted questions.  If the question already received an upvoted question it cannot be deleted.

Comment: @mast without knowing the question(s) it's hard to provide a really useful answer.

Comment: @Ramhound what if you got a question you thought was good you get downvotes then nothing. For like a couple of days then more downvotes come. (No answers) just downvotes. Would you delete it then?

Comment: @JcbJoe - I would edit the question and improve it. If I still didn't get feedback I would ask the meta community about the question.  The very last thing, I would do be to delete the question, especially if I had other downvoted questions in the past.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound lesson learned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, if the system does not allow you to delete a question of your own, you could flag your question for deletion by a moderator, but they will usually decline the flag, as [explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

Please take the time reading the last paragraph (*"If I flag my post with a request to delete it, what will happen?"*) of that meta page, and make sure you understand the reasons given there why questions with upvoted answers will usually not be eligible for deletion any more.

That leaves you basically with the following options:

- Improve the wording of the question up to the point where it could "help others in the future". Since someone else answered your question and got upvotes for it, at least one or two community members saw probably more value in it than yourself, hence this is often possible.
- If you have no clue how to do the former, ask a question at the individual meta site about how your specific question might be improved, or whether the community shares your point of view that the question is not valuable for the site and cannot be improved. If you get support from the community for the latter, that should convince a moderator to accept your request for deletion, or to convince some high rep community members to cast a delete vote.
- [Have the question dissociated from your account.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa) - That does not delete the question, but it hands the problem over to the community, and the low-quality question will not longer make your account "look bad", if that's your concern.
- Do nothing. If your question has really such a low quality as you think, sooner or later it will be closed and users with enough rep can delete it after 48 hours, even with upvoted answers.

Let me add I had a short look into the questions you had asked on Stackoverflow in the past. Even the ones with the most negative voting score give me the impression of having a clear value for the community, especially when you read them in combination with the answers they got. So I see definitely no reason why those questions should be deleted.