# Stop receiving edit notifications for an old post

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications, global-inbox

Some time ago (about 10 years) I created this post in the Photography Meta:

[Image of the week "hall of fame"](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

Since the post is a sort of repository for all the "image of the week" contests, I keep receiving a notification each time the post is edited (and this happens one time a week :).

Is there a way to stop receiving this kind of notifications?

Comment: This would be a nice _option_ to have. But it should be an option that could be toggled on/off (best if per post). I already don't get notifications about some edits that I _want_ to be notified about as is.

Comment: You can have the post disassociated, I think. I don't know how that works exactly on CW posts.

Comment: @41686d6564 then follow those posts.

Comment: @Luuklag That means I have to follow every single question/answer of mine.

Comment: "is there a way to" = [support]. Was your intent to ask if there was a way to stop this, or to ask for there to be a way?

Comment: @Luuklag Actually, I just realized you can't follow your own posts (which kind of makes sense).

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround, you could ask for [post dissociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/295232). You'll no longer be the author of the post, and if you don't [follow it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) you'll no longer get notifications about edits. The FAQ post contains some warnings about this procedure but IMHO it's a valid option here. It's a community wiki so you have enough reputation to edit it anyway. The only downside may be that you lose a high-scoring question on your Photography Meta profile...

Comment: ...which also contribute to gaining badges that might be revoked after the dissociation.