# How can I stop receiving notifications from a certain site?

Tags: support, notifications

I was trying out [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), and asked a few questions on the [Emacs Stack Exchange site](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tour). I now stuck to [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) and no longer care about Emacs. Is there a way I can stop getting notifications about answers to those Emacs questions other than deleting them?

(E.g., when I use Stack Overflow I don't want notifications about answers to Emacs questions.) I have researched it and the unfollow functionality does not seem applicable.

Comment: Likely trigger: [This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55915/evil-mode-send-escape-before-alt-meta-command/72130#72130) was edited yesterday.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to [delete your account on Emacs.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/295232). You won't get notifications generated by activity on 'your' posts anymore. On the other hand, how many notifications do you actually get? Your last post there was more than two years ago ...

Requesting [post disassociation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/295232) would probably work as well, but that might take more time.

The 'unfollow' option indeed only works for other users' posts which you have followed before, and is not applicable to your case.

Comment: It would be nice if the questions persisted after deleting ones account, cause they probably help other uses.

Comment: @run_the_race The questions do persist.