# How can I delete my wrong accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, deleted-answers

Similar questions were asked before, but the answers recommend to edit the wrong answer to make it correct which does not suit me: after reading the question again I noticed that the question is rather broad and I neither have desire nor competence to answer it.

I just want to delete my wrong answer and forget it, but I can't. As a result, I left *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* about a year ago, and I felt discomfort here because I misled the questioner, but maybe where is another solution?

PS: This is not the first time I see that when programmers are solving a minor problem they introduce a bigger problem and keep it.

Comment: Which answer (and which question) are you referring to?

Comment: I forgot (it was about a year ago or more). It does not matter, the question is general.

Comment: No. I know that I can't delete my accepted answer. But "You can't" is not an answer I am looking for. I want a solution.

Comment: You can ask the OP to unaccept then you can delete. Instead of leaving the site you could ask to [disassociate the answer from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa). (Well, you can still do it.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Thanks.This option is interesting.

Comment: You may not think it is an ideal answer but if the OP accepted it perhaps they found it helpful in ways you did not anticipate.

Comment: You also have the option of editing the answer to highlight what is wrong (or insufficient or whatever) with it, so as not to mislead future readers.

Comment: I finally accepted "wise" point of view proposed in two last comments and edited my answer to make it free from errors. It does not make sense to do more now, years after the question was asked.

Comment: Leaving the site over one mistake seems like an overreaction.